# Каталог, в котором располагается Django

Tags: python, django, debian, linux

ОС -  Linux Debian. Начал читать книгу по Django, а там надо в консоли прописывать
`django-admin.py startproject mysite`.
Прописываю, выводит, что `django-admin.py` не найден. Видимо, надо указать полный путь к этому файлу, либо надо прописать путь к переменной среды `PATH`. Но ни то, ни другое сделать не могу, так как полного пути к этому файлу не знаю, а добавлять переменную среды не умею. Подскажите, что надо сделать, чтобы заработало?

Comment: Вероятно, стоит древняя джанга - сколько я работаю, а пути на django-admin.py никогда не прописывал...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu server 11.10, Python 2.7.2 при корректной документированной установке пакета

```
$python setup.py install
```

Установилось в `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`
Но при корректной инсталляции Django как обычного пакета все системные пути прописываются автоматически.

Answer (score 0):

разворачивал тестовый Django проект на Debian по [Этой статье](http://debianworld.ru/articles/ustanovka-i-nastrojka-apache-mod_wsgi-django-mysql-v-debian-ubuntu/) с некоторыми свими модификациями. там и ответ на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```
locate django-admin.py
```

Answer (score -2):

Вот пример пути под Windows:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts
```

Правой кнопкой на Мой компьютер, там Свойства, вкладка Дополнительно, кнопка Переменные среды. В окошке в области Системные переменные выбираешь `Path` и жмешь Изменить, в конце списка ставишь `;` и дописываешь вышеуказанный путь